# Ubuntu 13.04 not booting - Boot-repair not working

Tags: 13.04, windows-7, live-cd, boot-repair, testdisk

Here is the story of what happened and what I did tried.

1. First, I wanted to remove my Windows 7 from my computer, so I delete
   the partition.
2. After doing this, I remembered that I forgot to take something from
   the drive.
3. So following online instruction, I installed testdisk and followed
   instruction of how to recuperate the partition.
4. After that, I boot up my computer and got to a grub error.
5. So I loaded a Ubuntu Live CD and install boot-repair and used the
   recommended repair.
6. Then I boot up and it loaded directly to Windows 7 and Windows 7
   started a disk repair.
7. After that, when I boot up, I couldn't boot in Ubuntu.
8. So I booted a Live CD again and tried the advanced options in
   boot-repair to see if I could fix it, but the boot-repair isnt
   seeing grub.
9. So I installed testdisk to see my partition and here is what I got :

   ```
    1 * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800 [System Reserved]
    2 P HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20  7192 254 63  115348697
   Invalid FAT boot sector
    3 P FAT12                 7193   1  1  9151 254 63   31471272
    3 P FAT12                 7193   1  1  9151 254 63   31471272
    4 E extended LBA          9152   0  1 14593 254 63   87425730
    5 L HPFS - NTFS          11329   0 32 13286 254 63   31455239 [Storage]
   ```
10. And after a deeper search, I get the following :

    ```
         Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
     D HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800 [System Reserved]
     D HPFS - NTFS             12 223 19    25 159  5     204800
     D HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20  7192 254 63  115348697
     D HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20 14593  33 32  234231808
     D FAT12                 7193   1  1  9151 254 63   31471272
     D Linux                 7193  12 52 11328 210 18   66441216
    >D HPFS - NTFS           7225 239 55  7238 175 41     204800
     D Linux                 8781 251 47 12917 194 13   66441216
     D Linux                 8785   1  1 12920 198 30   66441216
     D Linux                 8787  87  5 12923  29 34   66441216
     D Linux                 8788  27  8 12923 224 37   66441216
     D Linux                 8788 222 11 12924 164 40   66441216
    ```

Is there anything I can do to repair this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any documentation of partition table layout before? Or do you remember details?

It looks like the two FAT12 partitions are just wrong.
And Linux is the one at 7193 to 11328.
Did you then have an extended with some unallocated (or swap?) and a NTFS data partition starting at 11329?

All the other D deleted look like versions before changing thing around to install LInux or Windows errors in writing new partition table.

See if you can change Linux partition to primary and write partition table. You may have to delete FAT12 incorrect ones first.

Comment: I had 2 NTFS partitions for Windows (about 60GB), one for boot an the other. Then I had 1 partition for Ubuntu (About 30GB), then I a swap that removed about two weeks ago since I didn't need it anymore (4GB), I then had a 16GB NTFS for Storage. At last I had 10GB not used since I'm using a SSD. How can I change the linux partition to primary and how can I write partition table?

Comment: I did use fdisk to write my partition table and it seems to be as it was before. The only problem left is that the partition that I have made for Ubuntu is in the format Linux instead of ext4. I can't manage to read file in this partition yet, I was wondering how I can change the format to ext4.